# Blazor Server Side and CSS transition, usage tips

Tags: .net, css-animations, blazor-server-side

I am writing to understand if what I'm doing is correct or if there are better methods to exploit the CSS transition.

I see that the system works in this way, using a string for the CSS class and then adding and removing the various CSS classes from the string.

What I was wondering is if there is a better way or if this can go just fine

Index.razor

```
<!--Div to change the class-->
<div @onclick="ChangeClassV3" id="myDiv2" class="@classeDiv"></div>




@code {

    /// <summary>
    /// Default CSS class
    /// </summary>
    private string classeDiv = "originalClass";


    private void ChangeClassV3()
    {
        // return to normal state
        if (classeDiv.Contains("animateClass"))
        {
            classeDiv = classeDiv + " " + "originalClass";
            classeDiv = classeDiv.Replace("animateClass", "").Trim();
            return;
        }

        //Add new class 
        classeDiv = classeDiv + " " + "animateClass";
        classeDiv = classeDiv.Replace("originalClass", "").Trim();
        return;
    }


}
```

site.css

```
.originalClass {
    transition: 1s;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}

.animateClass {
    transition: 1s;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Example here : https://blazorfiddle.com/s/fa55gzzz